# alignment of elements in a button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap drop down and on the button, I have a text and an icon. What I want is to align the text all the way to the left and align the icon all the way to the right without having to grid the button with other elements. Thanks in advance.

```css
.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  width: 40%;
  height: 10vh;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown button {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown button i {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.dropdown button::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        drop me
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your CSS are not needed, you can use some of bootstrap's utility classes to achieve the expected result.

- You don't have to use `.dropdown button::after{}` to remove bootstrap's default dropdown caret. Just remove `.dropdown-toggle` from the button.
- You can then use this `d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center` class to align the text and the icon.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary w-100 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        drop me
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```